# Passing additional parameters to j_security_check

Tags: java, parameters, jaas, j-security-check

In our application we need to let user select the desired datasource when logging in with form-based authentication, and I'm not sure if it's at all possible when using standard form-based authentication. I heard it was possible using TextInputCallback, but have no idea how (and where) to implement it.

Comment: TextInputCallback is part of JAAS.

Answer (score 0):

In the `web.xml` there could be maximum one `<login-config>` tag. It means that you cannot use more than one realm in one web application. So, you need a more or less container specific solution.

In Tomcat there is a [CombinedRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/CombinedRealm.html) which can uses other realms.

> Realm implementation that contains one or more realms. Authentication
>   is attempted for each realm in the order they were configured. If any
>   realm authenticates the user then the authentication succeeds. When
>   combining realms usernames should be unique across all combined
>   realms.

Maybe it matches with your requirements. If not and users exist in more than one realm (with the same username) you could use prefixes. For example set `"domain\myuser"` as the username.

If you use nested `JDBCRealm`s you could create a database view which contains the prefixed usernames (just concat the prefix with the username) and use this view as the user table.

Another approach is removing the prefix in a custom realm and call the container's `JDBCRealm` (or its other realms) but it needs some coding. Anyway, it shouldn't be too hard, already existed realms probably can be used with the delegate design pattern.

Comment: If I got your idea correctly, I need to modify the database to do this. But how about using Spring's AbstractRoutingDataSource to switch between them? It's a migration/integration project, so we can't alter the database settings nor add anything new to it.

Comment: If you use the `CombinedRealm` and the databases don't contain the same username you don't have to create the new view. If you use the `CombinedRealm` and the databases contain the same username you can write a custom realm (without modifying the databases). I don't know anything Spring's `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.